# Is there a way to see the automator script in text?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, script, remote-desktop

If i create some type of workflow on Automator, can I see the script in plain text?

For example, maybe get the script and push it out through Apple Remote Desktop to a remote computer?

Comment: Is the some reason you cannot just transfer the package created by Automator?

Answer (score 1):

While you could look at, copy and transfer, the contents of the **document.wflow** file found inside the **filename.workflow** bundle or **Automator** **filename.app** bundle, it's just XML, I'm not sure how much good it will do you as it will not open in the **Automator.app**.  It will open  with the **Automator Runner** however it may not run as intended, depends on what's in there.